# how to proof the inequality $n > \ln^3(n)\ln^2(\ln(n))$ for n > 1

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

how to prove the inequality $n > \ln^3(n)\ln^2(\ln(n))$ , n > 1 and n $\in${natural numbers}

I do not know if this holds, but I would like to prove that it holds, or if it doesn't, then with contradiction.

I tried to put both sides into exponent form with base $e$, but got nowhere. What should I do?

Comment: It is true.  The general rule: $\log n$ and $\log\log n$ grow **much** slower than $n$.

Comment: ... so it is true at least for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof.
For large $n$,
$$
\log n < n,\\
\log\log n < \log n\\
(\log\log n)^2 < (\log n)^2\\
(\log n)^3(\log\log n)^2 < (\log n)^5
 < (n^{1/5})^5 = n
$$
The last step used $\log n < n^{1/5}$.  This is true for large enough $n$.

Proof that $\log n < n^{1/5}$ for large $n$.  Using l'Hopital's rule,

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n^{1/5}} = 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{-1}}{(1/5)n^{-4/5}} = 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5}{n^{1/5}} = 0 .
$$

Comment: The other answer from @Derik states, that n < 13, the statement of n being bigger is false. So I think we can't use $n = 1,2,3$ to check by hand, or am I wrong?

Comment: Oh I see, the prerequisite that it's for large $n$ is put in this inequality :

$(\log n)^3(\log\log n)^2 < (\log n)^5$ 

right?

Comment: In a previous edit, I was wrong that $\log n < n^{1/5}$ for $n > 4$.  In fact it is true for $n > 332105$.  It is interesting that the OP is true for $1$ to $11$, then false for a long interval, and finally true again for very large $n$.  Computaton says it is true for $n > 1609$.

Answer (score 1):

> Not a 'real' answer, but it was too big for a comment. I think that you're looking for a solution without using a calculator or PC but maybe this gives some insight. I did only a quick search with the following bound: $2\le\text{n}\le10^3$.

I wrote and ran some [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
\[Alpha] = 10^3;
ParallelTable[
  If[TrueQ[n > Log[n]^3*Log[Log[n]]^2], n, Nothing], {n, 
   2, \[Alpha]}] //. {} -> Nothing
```

Running the code gives:

```
Out[1]={2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
```

So, for all the other values of $\text{n}$ between the bounds $2\le\text{n}\le10^3$ is your statement wrong, this implies that when $\text{n}\in\mathbb{N}\smallsetminus\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\right\}$:

$$\text{n}<\ln^3(\text{n})\ln^2(\ln(\text{n}))\tag1$$

Comment: Very interesting that it works only from 1 to 12. I guess it is impossible to prove that it holds for those n(between 1 and 12) by hand. For large n the prove that @GEdgar did does it's job.

Comment: $n>\ln^3(n)\ln^2(\ln(n))$ holds again for $n > 1609$.